# SIP 408:Request Timeout while creating account in zoiper

Tags: sip

I have downloaded `zoiper220-linux.tar.gz` and unzipped It but when I am trying to create account in it shows

**SIP 408: Request timeout error**

I have been trying this for days

Thanks in advance

Comment: What PBX/SIP server are you working with?

Comment: thanks for the reply but this problem is solved now,i am using asterisk 1.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to first register in soft phone with the username and password set in sip.conf

For more details check the [link](http://www.technologylair.org/2014/01/creating-asterisk-pbx-how-to-configure.html)