# SIP 408 Request Timeout for Freeswitch

Tags: freeswitch, pbx

I am trying to create an account on [Zoipher](http://www.zoiper.com/en). Saw some articles over [here](https://www.zoiper.com/en/documentation/windows-installation-and-configuration) regarding the configuration and setup. I have freeswitch installed on docker. I came across one similar article [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21719773/sip-408request-timeout-while-creating-account-in-zoiper) where someone else is facing the same problem but that is for Asterisk. Also, they are referring to create a SIP account in `sip.conf`. However, I couldn't find anything existing inside my freeswitch directory where I can create a SIP account before creating it on Zoipher softphone. Please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default FreeSWITCH configuration already has users `1000` to `1019`, with the password `1234`. There's a `directory/` folder with a bunch of XML in it.

The best and the quickest way to learn FreeSWITCH is with their book: https://www.packtpub.com/networking-and-servers/freeswitch-12

or through training (I did some training for a small team, can do that again)

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend using Docker for a VoIP server before Docker supports port ranges. You need to configure it to map UDP port ranges for RTP, and with current version of Docker you can only list every port explicitly. In the next release, they promise to support port ranges.

Comment: I did the following before running the freeswitch server on docker `docker run -d -p 0.0.0.0:2223:22 -p 82:80 -p 5060:5060/tcp -p 5060:5060/udp -p 16384:16384/udp -p 16385:16385/udp -p 16386:16386/udp -p 16387:16387/udp -p 16388:16388/udp -p 16389:16389/udp -p 16390:16390/udp -p 16391:16391/udp -p 16392:16392/udp -p 16393:16393/udp -p 5080:5080/tcp -p 5080:5080/udp --name <container_name_goes_here> <repository_name_goes_here>` Were you talking about explicit port declaration just like I did above?

Comment: yes. Once you're through this, you also need to limit the RTP ports on the freeswitch side.

Comment: 1)Yeah, I did limit the RTP ports as mentioned in the documentation below: https://beingasysadmin.wordpress.com/2014/06/16/dockerizing-freeswitch-docker-enters-telephony-world/

2)Could you tell me if I need to provide the IP address of the container of the docker where I am running the freeswitch while creating the account on Zoipher or the Internal IP of my computer? I figured out how to determine the IP address of the container using the following command `docker inspect <container_name> | grep IPAddress | cut -d '"' -f 4`

Comment: 3) Also, should I Turn Off my firewall on Windows 7 or 8 while testing Zoipher? Thanks

Comment: Zoiper should connect to the external IP address of your docker server. But you need to tell FreeSWITCH its external IP address too. As far as I remember, Zoiper did not require any firewall manipulations on my Windows. I would recommend to try FreeSWITCH first on a regular VPS -- you can get one really cheap at digitalocean.com, and later move your experience into a docker container.

Comment: Okay, I am trying to install freeswitch on CentOS now.

Comment: @Stainslav Sinyagin Everything worked fine with CentOS, however, when I am making test calls say for example on the number 9198, I couldn't hear anything. Does anybody know what could be the reason?

Comment: @John, you can find me in Skype (ssinyagin) or in Google Hangouts. Let's have a look at the server together. I'm available during the day till 6pm central European time.

Answer (score 0):

You can find SIP users' accounts in the `<freeswitch home directory>/conf/directory/default`. There are XML files with sip accounts, inside them you can configure UserID and passwords for SIP users.